# Contribution report not accurate for 2 or more patrons with same last name

Tags: civireport

Our contact name listing is first name last name, so to get an alphabetical report we created a custom field “Patron Last Name”.  We have patrons with the same last name (e.g., Jim Smith, Jane Smith).
A contribution summary report does not report these names separately; it either skips one patron entirely or lumps contributions from multiple patrons under the 1st name it comes across.
Contact ID seems the answer; marking the field in Group By runs OK but still leaves out at least one patron. If it is marked in both the Column and Group By areas, I get the message to make sure both those are marked. Any ideas would be helpful, thank you.
Running most current version of Civi under WordPress.

Comment: When you say contact name listing, do you mean Individual Display Name Format or Individual Sort Name Format? Its the latter that effects the sorting in reports and I would have thought you wanted this to be the default {contact.last_name}{, }{contact.first_name} which would give you what you want. What is the reason for having  it as {contact.first_name}{ }{contact.last_name} ?

Comment: Agree with Mick. Can't see any reason for a custom field for 'Last Name'. Perhaps you could check out https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/list?compid=2&reset=1 and explain which report you are using as your template

Comment: We are using the Household record for patron activity; when the records were imported from the old system a year ago, they came in as “John and Jane Smith”.  So when we run a standard reports, the listing is  alphabetized by the first name.  We added the Patron Last name to facilitate sorting.  This is just the standard Contribution Summary Report.  This is really 2 questions: one is the mashing together of the records with the same last name; the other why the system tells me that any field marked in Group By has to also be marked in Columns when that is already the case.

Comment: I haven't used households at all so am not sure I can help. In the comment you have John Smith and Jane Smith in one household, but is your problem in the question, are Jim Smith and Jane Smith are in different households?

Comment: I used John and Jane Smith to illustrate how the household contact name is entered. My problem is that we have multiple “Smiths”, some of whom live in the same retirement center so even have th3 same street address, although different apartment numbers.